# Utility type to extract a generic constraint from a typescript function?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this function:

```js
function foo<T extends Bar>(...) {
  ...
}
```

How do I extract the `Bar` from the above?

I was thinking something like:

```js
type ExtractGenericConstraint<T> = T extends ((infer U) => any)? U : never; // Pseudocode
```

My inferencing abilities aren't that great though.

This is what it would like:

```js
type Constraint = ExtractGenericConstraint<typeof foo> // Constraint == Bar
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if this weren't pseudocode; I don't think you'll be able to infer from constraints.  But whether you can get `Bar` out of that depends strongly on what's going on in those `...`.  Please [edit] to make this a [mre] others can drop into their own IDEs and maybe you'll get a useful answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Part of the question is actually that I don't really know what's inside the `...`. But I added some code to clarify a bit.

Comment: There is no type function that can extract the constraint from all function types matching that fragment.  If you were to provide some syntactically valid examples maybe someone would have a more helpful suggestion.  But without a [mre] I wouldn’t presume to guess.